# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error on a function with cursor inside

Tags: sql, function, cursor, sql-server-2012

I have a function which takes student id as input and returns the average grade of the student.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this bound error. Is it because of the FETCH next command?

The CourseEnrollment table has 2 columns, studentid, courseid and finalgrade

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PersonalAverage ( @StudentId VARCHAR(20) )

    RETURNS DECIMAL AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE @AverageGrade DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @TotalMarks INT
        DECLARE @NumberOfCourses INT

        SET @AverageGrade=0
        SET @TotalMarks=0
        SET @NumberOfCourses=0


        DECLARE CalculateAverage CURSOR FOR
        SELECT FinalGrade 
            FROM CourseEnrollment
                WHERE @StudentId=dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId

        OPEN CalculateAverage 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

        BEGIN

            SET @NumberOfCourses = @NumberOfCourses + 1
            SET @TotalMarks = @TotalMarks + dbo.CourseEnrollment.FinalGrade

            FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @TotalMarks
        END


        IF @NumberOfCourses>0

        BEGIN
            SET @AverageGrade = @TotalMarks/@NumberOfCourses
        END


        CLOSE CalculateAverage
        DEALLOCATE Calculateaverage


         RETURN @AverageGrade



    END;
```

Corrected Version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PersonalAverage ( @StudentId VARCHAR(20) )

    RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2) AS

    BEGIN

        DECLARE @FinalGrade INT
        DECLARE @AverageGrade DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @TotalMarks DECIMAL(5,2)
        DECLARE @NumberOfCourses INT

        SET @AverageGrade=0
        SET @TotalMarks=0
        SET @NumberOfCourses=0
        SET @FinalGrade=0


        DECLARE CalculateAverage CURSOR FOR
        SELECT dbo.CourseEnrollment.FinalGrade 
            FROM dbo.CourseEnrollment
                WHERE @StudentId=dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId AND dbo.CourseEnrollment.FinalGrade IS NOT NULL

        OPEN CalculateAverage 

        FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @FinalGrade 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN

            SET @NumberOfCourses = @NumberOfCourses + 1
            SET @TotalMarks = @TotalMarks + @FinalGrade

            FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @FinalGrade
        END


        IF @NumberOfCourses>0

        BEGIN
            SET @AverageGrade = @TotalMarks/@NumberOfCourses
        END


        CLOSE CalculateAverage
        DEALLOCATE Calculateaverage


         RETURN @AverageGrade



    END;
```

Comment: What is the full error message you get?

Comment: @Karl: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PersonalAverage, Line 29
The multi-part identifier "dbo.CourseEnrollment.FinalGrade" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you need an initial

   FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @TotalMarks

between

```
OPEN CalculateAverage
```

and

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
```

1. What Gordon said. The use of a cursor here is misguided, you can easily do this sort of calc using SQL aggregation. AVG...GROUP BY.
2. I suspect the error is in SET @TotalMarks = @TotalMarks + dbo.CourseEnrollment.FinalGrade as you there really is no reference to dbo.CourseEnrollment available in that line.

Note: I am having some trouble making the formatting stick.

with you declarations:

```
DECLARE @FinalGrade DECIMAL(5,2)
```

then
    OPEN CalculateAverage;
    FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @FinalGrade

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

```
BEGIN

  SET @NumberOfCourses = @NumberOfCourses + 1
  SET @TotalMarks = @TotalMarks + @FinalGrade   -- @FinalGrade

  FETCH NEXT FROM CalculateAverage INTO @FinalGrade
END
```

Comment: I added the extra FETCH line between OPEN and WHILE. Still the same error. For 1. It's something I'm learning so we're supposed to just try it.  For 2.  Yeah, the error is with that line. How can include the reference ?

Comment: Instead of fetching into \@TotalMarks you should fetch into \@finalgrade. Then the line that is erroring will be changes to SET \@TotalMarks = \@TotalMarks + \@FinalGrade and it should work. (not sure how to escape my \@'s correctly.)

Comment: I removed the error from that line by:

SET \@TotalMarks = @TotalMarks + (SELECT FinalGrade 
            FROM dbo.CourseEnrollment
             WHERE \@StudentId=dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId)

But now when I execute the function, I get this error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: You need to fetch into @finalgrade and use that from the cursor rather than the subquery you tried. I'll see if I can show in the answer.

Comment: There is no @FinalGrade. FinalGrade is from the table CourseEnrollment.

Comment: and that's part of the problem. Declare one.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was the problem. One last help, when I execute the function, I'm getting the correct integer value in return, but not the decimal part. 

DECLARE /@GetVal DECIMAL(5,2)
 SELECT /@GetVal=dbo.PersonalAverage('02-RBWeasley') 
 SELECT /@GetVal AS [Average Grade];

Comment: here a fiddle that shows the important stuff without the sproc wrapper. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9aef6/3/0 I'll look at the decimal issue.

Comment: Change to DECLARE @TotalMarks DECIMAL(5,2) and that should force your result to the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

First, a cursor is not needed for this calculation.  But, I think your problem is in this line:

```
    SELECT FinalGrade 
    FROM CourseEnrollment
    WHERE @StudentId=dbo.CourseEnrollment.StudentId
```

SQL Server has no way of knowing that `dbo.CourseEnrollment` actually refers to `CourseEnrollment`.  You should get in the habit of using table aliases:

```
    SELECT FinalGrade 
    FROM CourseEnrollment ce
    WHERE @StudentId = ce.StudentId
```

Comment: Same error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PersonalAverage, Line 30
The multi-part identifier "CE.FinalGrade" could not be bound.

Comment: That would mean that the column `courseEnrollment.FinalGrade` doesn't exist.

Comment: I rechecked, it does.